# Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

Требуется вывести в datagrid enum в виде combobox, посмотрел здесь как это реализуется https://www.cyberforum.ru/wpf-silverlight/thread1798263.html, при создании combobox непосредственно в окне приложения всё работает, но при попытке записи combobox в datagrid при выборе элемента вылезает ошибка null reference exeption, в самой разметке так-же есть ошибка

[image: []]

Мой EnumItemSource

```
 class EnumItemSource : Collection<string>, IValueConverter
{
    Type type;
    IDictionary<Object, Object> valueToNameMap;
    IDictionary<Object, Object> nameToValueMap;

    public Type Type
    {
        get { return this.type; }
        set
        {
            if (!value.IsEnum)
                throw new ArgumentException("Type is not an enum.", "value");
            this.type = value;
            Initialize();
        }
    }

    public Object Convert(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return this.valueToNameMap[value];
    }

    public Object ConvertBack(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return this.nameToValueMap[value];
    }

    void Initialize()
    {
        this.valueToNameMap = this.type
            .GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
            .ToDictionary(fi => fi.GetValue(null), GetDescription);
        this.nameToValueMap = this.valueToNameMap
            .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Value, kvp => kvp.Key);
        Clear();
        foreach (String name in this.nameToValueMap.Keys)
            Add(name);
    }

    static Object GetDescription(FieldInfo fieldInfo)
    {
        var descriptionAttribute =
            (DescriptionAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(fieldInfo, typeof(DescriptionAttribute));
        return descriptionAttribute != null ? descriptionAttribute.Description : fieldInfo.Name;
    }
}
```

xaml код ресурса

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <enums:EnumItemSource x:Key="EnumItemSource" Type="{x:Type equipmentModel:TypeMatrix}"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте сделал бы нечто [подобное](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4398752) и короче, и проще, и логичней. По поводу вашей проблемы, ну так поставьте точку остановки в предоставленном коде и посмотрите что конкретно у вас отдает NULL, потом разбирайтесь почему это NULL.

Comment: Здравствуйте, в том то и проблема, что ошибка возникает извне, как я думаю на уровне разметки, по этому отследить её я не могу, единственное что, она возникает при возвращении значения из метода ConvertBack, но возвращается не null

Comment: Когда вы пишете `{Binding Value, Converter=конвертер}`, то дизайнер студии фоном запускает этот конвертер и пытается преобразовать входное значение, а оно по умолчанию у `Value` = null (это я сейчас про `SelectedMatrix` говорю). Другими словами, в строке `return this.valueToNameMap[value];` у вас `value` равно null, а вы пытаетесь взять из словаря `null`. Делайте проверку тогда, например банальную `if (value == null) return null;`, либо `return value == null ? null :  this.valueToNameMap[value];`. То есть в самом начале конвертации, если значение пустое, то нам нет смысла его преобразовывать.